# how to update a file

Tags: bash

I have been looking for some example of how to update a file that is already exist in bash. so far i haven found any. I'm using parameter as my first start for the existent, copy file to a different directory. can you guys help me please, show me some example of anyway to update a file.

Comment: Can you try rephrasing this?  I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do.

Comment: for instant, a file1 have data A,b,c. now file1 is re-written. and you want to update it. i think update and replace is the same right?  i'm not sure if the word update is the correct word. it is like the file is old and you want to replace the old file with new one. does it has to have the same file name? i don't think it matter right?

Comment: Are you asking how to copy a new file over the top of an existing file?  Perhaps `cp newfile file1` is what you want?

Comment: ok...it like this..File 1 have a,b, and c. later one File 1 has more feature which is d and e. i want to update the old file 1 so it have all feature which is a,b,c,d,and e. it like i have a older version and i want to up date it to a newer version. kinda like overwrite a file.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the append operator ">>" to add to the end of a file.

For example:
Echo "Job completed successfully." >> /var/log/backuplog

Will add "Job completed successfully." to the end of backuplog.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by "updating a file"? Do you want to append text to it? This would be done with something like  `echo "My text" >> filename`, which prints the text "My text" to the end of the file `filename`. If you just want to get the time of the last change updated, you can use `touch filename`. Many ways, so please tell us what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't looking to append to a file, and instead you are looking to modify the content you may want to take a look at [sed](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sed).  A command like `sed -i -e 's/foo/bar/'` would replace all instances of foo i the file with bar.  Far more complex edits are possible, sed is extremely versatile.

Comment: @Zoredache: echo...echo...

Comment: @Dennis Williamson, Well isn't that neat, I have never seen that before.  I don't think I did anything that should have caused a dup post.

Comment: i did try but it came out like this:    sed: -i may not be used with stdin

Comment: @Alex Vo, the `-i` is meant for modifying a file in-place.  If you want to do something with STDIN, then get rid of the `-i`.

Comment: is sed and awk has something to do with overwrite a file. like i have a older version and i want to up date it to a newer version. kinda like overwrite a file. like File 1 have a,b, and c. later one File 1 has more feature which is d and e. i want to update the old file 1 so it have all feature which is a,b,c,d,and e.

Comment: first i want to thanks all you guys for trying to help me out.